# Как настроить возможность режима правки для элементов в Bitrix шаблоне, если используется vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, битрикс

Не работает режим правки в шаблоне, который вызывается в смонтированном с помощью vue.js блоке.

Подскажи пожалуйста, есть ли возможность настроить режим правки в шаблоне, если используется vue.js?

Этот код я использую, чтобы включить возможность режима правки для элементов. Но подключая vue.js, этот код не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В режиме редактирования битрикс добавляет в конец блока свои скрипты для показа диалогов редактирования, а vue не любит, когда внутри его шаблонов появляются скрипты. Поэтому нужно убрать скрипты из блоков.

Если в настройках параметров главного модуля включить режим "Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы", то скрипты переместятся из блоков в конец страницы. Но нужно будет протестировать работу своих скриптов в случае, если они зависят друг от друга.